# first letter of every word -im getting the last word two times

Tags: python-3.x, string

My problem is to input a string and get the third word of the sentence. That part is resolved. The second part is to get the first letter of everyword but for some reason im getting two times the last word of the sentence

```
def words():
    global sent
    sent=input('enter a sentence - ')
    word=sent.split()
    return sent.split()[2]
print (words())

def first_letter():
    word=sent.split()
    c=0
    for j in sent:
        if j==' ':
            c+=1
    num_words=c+1
    for k in range(0,num_words):
        frst_letter=word[k]
    return word[k]
print(first_letter())
```

I expect the program to give me the first letter of every word in the sentence

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sent = "hello there, how do you do?"

def first_letter():
    word=sent.split()
    return [c[0] for c in word]
print(first_letter())
```

**output**

```
['h', 't', 'h', 'd', 'y', 'd']
```